# Finding circuit values that produce resonance at the specified frequency

Tags: equation-solving

Trying to come up with component values for the Butterworth-Van Dyke equivalent circuit so that it resonates at 1.1 MHz

[image: Butterworth-Van Dyke equivalent circuit]

```
z1 := -I/(ω*c2) + I*ω*l1 + r1
z2 := -I/(ω*c1)
z := (z1*z2)/(z1 + z2)
zr := ComplexExpand[Arg[z]]
zd := D[zr, ω]

Solve[{zd > 10^6, c2 > 0, c2 < 500*10^-9, c1 > 100*10^-12, 
  c1 < 500*10^-9, l1 > 1*10^-3, l1 < 3000*10^-3, 
  r1 == 10, ω == 2*π*1.1*10^6}, {c1, c2, l1}]
```

In my understanding the amplitude of the impedance `zr` at the resonant point is non-continuous so the derivative will be approaching infinity, not sure how to specify this or how to specify in other way that I'm solving for the minimum of `zr` at the predefined point.

Expecting `Solve` to give me conditional solutions that I can pick arbitrary values from and narrow it down to one particular set of values.

At the moment it gives me this:

[image: is not a variable error]

Comment: Have you tried this in a fresh notebook? The error suggests that one of your variables has an existing
 definition.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed this error, trying to move further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited to fix the error that @rw3103 caught, and to use `Together` to insure the right denominator.

First, consider that `symbol := expression` is almost never what you want. `symbol = expression` has the advantage that it computes the expression (as far as it can) right there.

Avoid feeding approximate numbers (anything with a decimal point) to symbolic manipulation machinery like `Solve`. This can cause trouble. Use symbols or exact numbers.

For these problems, I tend to work in the Laplace domain rather than Fourier, using the complex frequency `s==I ω`. Simpler. So:

```
z1 = 1/(s*c2) + s*l1 + r1;
z2 = 1/(s*c1);
z = (z1*z2)/(z1 + z2)
(* (r1 + 1/(c2 s) + l1 s)/(c1 s (r1 + 1/(c1 s) + 1/(c2 s) + l1 s)) *)
```

Now, linear network theory tells us that resonances correspond to pairs of the "poles" of `z`, the places where its denominator is zero. Use `Together` to get the whole denominator.

```
poles = Solve[Denominator[Together[z]] == 0, s]
(* {{s -> 0}, {s -> (-c1 c2 r1 - 
Sqrt[c1] Sqrt[c2] Sqrt[-4 c1 l1 - 4 c2 l1 + c1 c2 r1^2])/(
  2 c1 c2 l1)}, {s -> (-c1 c2 r1 + 
  Sqrt[c1] Sqrt[c2] Sqrt[-4 c1 l1 - 4 c2 l1 + c1 c2 r1^2])/(
  2 c1 c2 l1)}} *)
```

The imaginary part of the solution is the angular frequency (the real part is the damping). So, to get the resonant frequency:

```
res = Simplify[Im[s] /. poles[[3]], {c1 > 0, c2 > 0, r1 > 0, l1 > 0}]
(* Im[Sqrt[-4 c1 l1 - 4 c2 l1 + c1 c2 r1^2]]/(2 Sqrt[c1 c2] l1) *)
```

I used `poles[[3]]` to get the positive frequency solution.

This expression tells us a lot about the solution space. The numerator will be zero unless `-4 c1 l1 - 4 c2 l1 + c1 c2 r1^2` is negative, so this tells you when the damping is small enough to have a resonance.

You can further explore the solution space with `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[{res == w, w > 0, c1 > 0, c2 > 0, r1 > 0, l1 > 0}, c1]
(* l1 > 0 && r1 > 0 && w > 0 && c2 > (4 l1)/(r1^2 + 4 l1^2 w^2) && 
  c1 == (4 c2 l1)/(-4 l1 + c2 r1^2 + 4 c2 l1^2 w^2) *)
```

This gives you `c1` for the desired frequency, along with the minimum value for c2 to avoid overdamping.